# How does strace know to use /bin/echo instead of failing on a built-in

Tags: linux, bash, strace

When I do `strace echo hello`, I see it is using `/bin/echo`, but built-in `echo` should be found first.  Is it a functionality of strace to skip built-in commands? strace -- version 4.5.19

I understand that strace won't work on built-in commands the way it works on system executables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because strace isn't a shell, strace uses exec.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb.  OK I was thinking about it the wrong way.  You are correct, I will accept the answer when the time period passes.

Answer (score 3):

When you type a command to the shell (e.g., `echo hello world`), the shell interprets that command and will check to see if a shell built-in command can be used before looking for a separate executable.

When you use `strace`, you are asking it to locate an executable and run it on your behalf.  Unlike the shell, `strace` has no built-in commands of its own.